# Please how can I write this equation in latex?

Tags: equations

[image]

Please how can I write this equation in latex?

Comment: What have you tried? Which part do you have trouble with? This is simply fraction and left right delimiter

Answer (score 2):

Is it difficult?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
 B_{v} = \frac{\mu_{0}I_{p}}{4\pi R}\biggl[\ln\biggl(\frac{8R}{a}\biggr) - \frac{3}{2} + \beta_{p} + \frac{l_{i}}{2}\biggr]
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I guess it is difficult for the OP. Otherwise he wouldn't ask for help.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: I understood. :). That is why I answered. May be that phrase should be changed.. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
\begin{equation*}
B_v = \dfrac{\mu_0 I_p}{4 \pi R} \left[ \ln \left( \dfrac{8 R}{a} \right) -dfrac{3}{2} + \beta_p + \dfrac{l_i}{2}\right]
\end{equation*}
```

Comment: Please, don't use `$$` in LaTeX.

Comment: @egreg, I corrected it. But, why not?

Comment: @Furihr: See [Why is `\[` … `\]` preferable to `$$`?](http://goo.gl/GvmWy)